# how to use dcc.Store() for dictionary of dataframe

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dictionary to store lots of dataframes, ie. dict1={'key1':df1,'key2':df2,'key3':df3}

Now I am using dcc.Store() to share these dictionary data between callbacks.

firstly, I store the dictionary into dcc.Store() using json.dumps(dict1), then I got an error of TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable.

so how do I store dictionary of dataframe into dcc.Store()? do I have to convert all the dataframe before putting them into the dictionary? It will re-work all my codes. Is it possible to do it without converting each dataframe to json and just work on the dictionary?

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data'),
    [
    Input('load-area-data','n_clicks'),
    ],

    
    prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)
def change_area_data(n_clicks):  #radio_value,range_slider_values
    
    s1=json.dumps(dict1) 
    return s1
```

then, I am loading the dictionary from dcc.Store().

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("timeplot-graph", "figure"),
        Output("timeplot-markdown", "children"),
    ],
    [
        Input("plot-well-prod", "n_clicks"),
    ],
    [
        State('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data'),
    ],
    
    prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)

def change_well_time_graphs(n_clicks,well_cell, well_data,json_dict):
    

    df = json.loads(json_dict)
   
     
    (fig,markdown_text)=make_graph(df)

    print('Done Creating Graphes')
        
    return (fig,markdown_text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable` means you need to convert your dataframe into something that is JSON-compatible (e.g. a dictionary). Then, you will need to pass into `dcc.Store()` a tuple or a list of that json-serializable object (e.g. a list of a dict). Once you want to read that dataframe in another callback, you just convert the `dcc.Store` object back into a dataframe. Here is an example of how you could do this in your code:

```py
@app.callback(
    [Output('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data')],
    [Input('load-area-data','n_clicks')]
    , prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load

)
def change_area_data(n_clicks):  #radio_value,range_slider_values
    s1 = [df.to_dict()]
    return s1 


@app.callback(
    [
        Output("timeplot-graph", "figure"),
        Output("timeplot-markdown", "children"),
    ],
    [
        Input("plot-well-prod", "n_clicks"),
    ],
    [
        State('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data'),
    ], prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)
def change_well_time_graphs(n_clicks,well_cell, well_data,json_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict, orient='index')   
    (fig,markdown_text)=make_graph(df)
    print('Done Creating Graphes')
        
    return (fig,markdown_text)
```

EDIT:
In the case of having a dictionary of dataframes that you wish to store in a `dcc.Store`, then the same approach applies but by doing this for each dataframe in the dictionary, then sending the dict to the store, then iterating through each dictionary in the callback and converting that back into a dataframe, here's an example of that for your code:

```py
@app.callback(
    [Output('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data')],
    [Input('load-area-data','n_clicks')]
    , prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load

)
def change_area_data(n_clicks):  #radio_value,range_slider_values
    temp_dict = dict1
    for key, df in temp_dict.items():
        temp_dict[key] = df.to_dict()
    return [temp_dict]


@app.callback(
    [
        Output("timeplot-graph", "figure"),
        Output("timeplot-markdown", "children"),
    ],
    [
        Input("plot-well-prod", "n_clicks"),
    ],
    [
        State('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data'),
    ], prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)
def change_well_time_graphs(n_clicks,well_cell, well_data,json_dict):
    df_list = []
    for _, dic in json_dict.items():
        df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index')) 
    # the rest of your logic using the list of df's "df_list"
    .
    .
    .
    return (fig,markdown_text)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, in your line of s1 = [df.to_dict()], what is df? is it a single dataframe?  How to deal with a dictionary of dataframe, ie. dict1={'k1':df1,'k2':df2,'k3':df3}  Thanks

Comment: Hey Roudan, in the case of a dict of dfs, then just convert each df in the dict to a dict (which will give you a dict of dicts), then send that master dict back to the store. then in the callback you want to retrieve the store, just iterate through the dict of dicts and re convert each one back into a df. I'll edit the answer for this case in a bit.

Comment: Thank you Daniel

Comment: Updated answer for dict of df's, @roudan

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will take a look at tonight and accept the answer after that if works. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries Roudan, good luck on your project!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241844/discussion-between-daniel-al-mouiee-and-roudan).

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have a question on this line: def change_well_time_graphs(n_clicks,well_cell, well_data,json_dict):
df_list = []
for dic in json_dict:
df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict, orient='index'))
so the df_list have only one item, right?
and I think it should be df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index'))
you wrote from_dict(json_dict), I think it should be from_dict(dic),
if there is only one item in the df_list, could I get my original df back using df=df_list[0]

Answer (score 1):

If there really are a lot of dataframes, it may make sense to use an in-memory database such as redis for anything but the shortest-lived project. A `dict` of dataframes is lightweight but may not be efficient for later processing.